# "During this hour" vs. "In this hour"

Tags: phrases

"This took place in this hour."
"This took place during this hour."

Is there any difference between the phrases "in this hour" and "during this hour"?

Comment: Well, there's certainly a kind of *similarity* between those two constructions: no one would ever employ them!

Comment: So they actually mean the same?

Comment: My comment was a little joke. I was saying no native speaker would ever say "*... took place in this hour*" or "*... took place during this hour*". We simply don't phrase the idea that way. To explore this idea more, you can ask for details on our special site dedicated to people learning English as a foreign language: [ELL.se].

Comment: @DanBron, So what they say instead? Please give us an example.

Comment: @Eilia As I told OP, more details can be gained by asking this question on our sister site dedicated to people trying to learn to speak English like a native speaker would, [ELL.se].

Comment: With regard to @Dan Bron's comment that we wouldn't say these constructions ... essentially, it's because *this hour* means *now*, and we can't say *during now* or *in now*. We do use both *during that hour* and *in that hour* — see [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+that+hour%2C+during+that+hour&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20that%20hour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduring%20that%20hour%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: You can talk about a specific hour in this way, like on the TV show *24* they used to say "The following events took place between 0200 and 0300 on the 31st May"; in such a context it would make sense to say "in this hour". But I can't tell if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: 'This took place this very hour.'

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @DanBron, such constructions are a bit strange. I think, following alternatives may be useful.

> ...took place **during the hour**. (16 occurrences in Google Book)
>
> ...took place **within the hour**. (18 occurrences in Google Book)

While,

> "This took place in this hour." (no occurrence in Google Book)
>
> ...took place during this hour. (9 occurrences in Google Book)

Moreover, for more info :

During vs. Within (http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/during-or-within.2461225/)

During vs. In (http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/preps_during-in.html)

and ([speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/prepositions/prepositions-of-time-during-for-over-or-by-until](http://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/prepositions/prepositions-of-time-during-for-over-or-by-until))

Comment: Curiously, if you scroll to the second page of results for each of your first two suggestions, [*took place during the hour*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22took+place+during+the+hour%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22took+place+during+the+hour%22&tbm=bks&start=10) actually has a total of 17 results, but the same for [*took place within the hour*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22took+place+within+the+hour%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22took+place+within+the+hour%22&tbm=bks&start=10) has 18. Google Books "estimated results" are often highly suspect.

Comment: Ohh, it is even worse than it looks for the first suggestion. There are only 16 occurrences.

Comment: Piling on the agony (and making no concessions to *learners*, who should be seeking enlightenment on ELL), I'd also point out that in casual speech I wouldn't necessarily bother with a preposition at all - *It happened this past hour* is fine by me.